# tomcat7 - how to enable tomcat manager for a specific domain

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I am trying to configure Tomcat Manager on 2 domains.

I am accessing the Tomcat Host Manager using the IP address of the server.

Now, once I have added the 2 domains via Host Manager, I am trying to access the Tomcat manager app for each domain(so that I can deploy apps to each domain). However I am getting Http 404 error for both domains' manager apps.

Is there something I am missing here? How do I enable Tomcat Manager so that I can access it using the domain names ie http://domain.com:8080/manager/html

Comment: Did you read http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html? Is DNS working correctly on your client and on the host, i.e. do both hostnames resolve correctly to the server's IP address?

Comment: @fuero I removed the mapping from Host manager, and in my domain registrar I added A records mapping the 2 domains with the IP address of the server-- now I am able to open both the domains-> manager apps... but does that mean that I can deploy apps to both domains separately? thanks....

Comment: @Arvind I know this is old, but did you find a solution?